# How to search based on value in list in cassandra database 2.2.1

Tags: list, search, dictionary, cassandra

```
create table tbl_master_values (
dbid int primary key,
user_dbid int, reg_dbid int,
module_dbid int,
fields_value map<text,list<text>>,
created_date timestamp,
modified_date timestamp);

CREATE INDEX idx_fields_value ON tbl_master_values (keys(fields_value));
```

Fields_values column contains this value:

```
{'287': ['28'], '288': [''], '289': [''], '291': ['33'], '295': [''],'309': ['214', '215']}
```

Now I want to search based on value in list inside map of fields_value column. I also tried this:

```
cqlsh:sampledb> select * from tbl_master_values where fields_value['309'] contains '215';
```

It shows error like:

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="No secondary indexes on
the restricted columns support the provided operators: 'fields_value = <value>'"

cqlsh:crmdb> select * from tbl_master_values where fields_value['309']=['215'];
```

It shows error like:

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="No secondary indexes on 
the restricted columns support the provided operators: 'fields_value = <value>'"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an index on the entry, not only on the map key

Try this

```
CREATE INDEX idx_fields_value ON tbl_master_values (ENTRIES(fields_value));
```

But more generally, this kind of secondary index does not scale very well with the cluster size because each request will hit a lot of nodes (number of node/RF to be exact)

Comment: cqlsh:crmdb> select * from tbl_master_values where fields_value['309']='214';
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid STRING constant (214)
 for "value(fields_value)" of type frozen<list<text>>"

Comment: `select * from tbl_master_values where fields_value['309']=['214']`--> You must put square brackets around the value of the map because it is a List

Comment: '309': ['214', '215']    In this i want to check list contain 214 or not

Comment: Since the list is *frozen*, you can query only on the **entire** content of the list, e.g. give me all maps where list content = xxx. You cannot only ask whether the frozen list contains some element